# How to set the Tab Bar title in iOS 13?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am trying to set a bigger font in the tab bar's title fields, but it doesn't work. What I tried changes the size of the icon and the font of the text field in the view. The title in the bar remains unchanged. As you can see I tried many ways (commented lines) and neither of them works.

```
struct DetailView: View {

var vehicle: Vehicle

var body: some View {
    
    TabView {
       DataView()
        .tabItem {
            Text("Dane")
            .font(.system(size: 18.0, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
            Image(systemName: "list.bullet")
//.font(.system(size: 30)).bold()//(Font.system(.largeTitle, design: .rounded).weight(.heavy).bold())
        }
        
        RefuelingListView()
            .font(.system(size: 20.0, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
            .tabItem {
                Text("Wpisy")
                .bold()
                .font(Font.system(.largeTitle, design: .rounded).weight(.heavy))
                Image(systemName: "list.bullet")
               // .font(.system(size: 19))
        }//.font(.largeTitle)
   // }
         //   .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle()).font(.system(size: 20))
 //        .onAppear() {
//            UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = .red
    }
    //.font(Font.system(.largeTitle, design: .rounded).weight(.heavy))
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding a custom initializer for the tab bar like this:

```
struct DetailView: View {

var vehicle: Vehicle

init() {
    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)], for: [])
}

var body: some View {
        // Rest of code
    }
}
```

Comment: Good idea, but I set it at the end of the TabView in .onAppear(){}
Thank you.